# Assembly What are *ALL* possible arithmetic possibilities in brackets?

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

I'm making a x86 asm to C code emulator.. and for my parser I am up to the bracket parsing

`QWORD PTR [` to `]`

`DWORD PTR [` to `]`

`WORD PTR [` to `]`

`BYTE PTR [` to `]`

`MOV X, [` to `]`

`LEA X, [` to `]`

For now I will ignore..

`MMWORD PTR[]`

`XMMWORD PTR[]`

`FWORD PTR []`

`TBYTE PTR []`

I want to know what are all the possible mathematical arithmetic can that be placed in the brackets

Most complex I have encountered is..
`[EBP+ECX*4-E0]`

The reason I have to parse is to convert `E0` to `0x000000E0` then  `4` to `0x00000004`

As far as I know `+`, `-`, `*` are possible is `\` and or `/` possible too, or how about dots? `.`?

I figure best way to split every instruction which contains brackets `[]` to get inner math.
Then split the inner math by 1 char delimiters `+-*`.

I want to make sure I get them all? is division ever possible in these? or not how about XOR/OR/AND/NOT ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe these tables for to build a Mod R/M-Byte is helpfull to show wich combination is possible for to build an address with the 16 bit and 32 bit base and index registers.

```
Format of Postbyte(Mod R/M from Intel)
--------------------------------------
MM RRR MMM

MM  - Memeory addressing mode
RRR - Register operand address
MMM - Memoy operand address

RRR Register Names
Filds  8bit  16bit  32bit
000    AL     AX     EAX
001    CL     CX     ECX
010    DL     DX     EDX
011    Bl     BX     EBX
100    AH     SP     ESP
101    CH     BP     EBP
110    DH     SI     ESI
111    BH     DI     EDI

---

16bit memory (No 32 bit memory address prefix)
MMM   Default MM Field
Field Sreg     00        01          10             11=MMM is reg
000   DS       [BX+SI]   [BX+SI+o8]  [BX+SI+o16]
001   DS       [BX+DI]   [BX+DI+o8]  [BX+DI+o16]
010   SS       [BP+SI]   [BP+SI+o8]  [BP+SI+o16]
011   SS       [BP+DI]   [BP+DI+o8]  [BP+DI+o16]
100   DS       [SI]      [SI+o8]     [SI+o16]
101   DS       [DI]      [DI+o8]     [SI+o16]
110   SS       [o16]     [BP+o8]     [BP+o16]
111   DS       [BX]      [BX+o8]     [BX+o16]
Note: MMM=110,MM=0 Default Sreg is DS !!!!

32bit memory (Has 67h 32 bit memory address prefix)
MMM   Default MM Field
Field Sreg     00        01          10             11=MMM is reg
000   DS       [EAX]     [EAX+o8]    [EAX+o32]
001   DS       [ECX]     [ECX+o8]    [ECX+o32]
010   DS       [EDX]     [EDX+o8]    [EDX+o32]
011   DS       [EBX]     [EBX+o8]    [EBX+o32]
100   SIB      [SIB]     [SIB+o8]    [SIB+o32]
101   SS       [o32]     [EBP+o8]    [EBP+o32]
110   DS       [ESI]     [ESI+o8]    [ESI+o32]
111   DS       [EDI]     [EDI+o8]    [EDI+o32]
Note: MMM=110,MM=0 Default Sreg is DS !!!!

---

SIB is (Scale/Base/Index)
SS BBB III
Note: SIB address calculated as:
<sib address>=<Base>+<Index>*(2^(Scale))

Fild   Default Base
BBB    Sreg    Register   Note
000    DS      EAX
001    DS      ECX
010    DS      EDX
011    DS      EBX
100    SS      ESP
101    DS      o32        if MM=00 (Postbyte)
SS      EBP        if MM<>00 (Postbyte)
110    SS      ESI
111    DS      EDI

Fild  Index
III   register   Note
000   EAX
001   ECX
010   EDX
011   EBX
100              never Index SS can be 00
101   EBP
110   ESI
111   EDI

Fild Scale coefficient
SS   =2^(SS)
00   1
01   2
10   4
11   8
```

Comment: Also note that most assemblers allow much more than the opcode seems to support. For example, instead of only allowing an offset to be added they can allow an offset to be subtracted (but actually add a negative number). Another example is `mov eax,[eax*5]` (which is actually `mov eax,[eax*4+eax]`). Then there's `mov eax,[eax*9 + foo - bar + hello * 3 - world/8]` (where the assembler converts a constant expression into a single constant offset)

Answer (score 2):

What's inside the brackets are address expressions. The Intel x86 family of processors supports certain address operations, like having a base register, adding an offset, and scaling with 2,4 or 8. Some assemblers allow dotted references to fields in structures as part of the base offset expression. Except for calculating the base offset, the 'math' inside the brackets is not math done at assembly time but the encoding of the address portion of the instruction to be calculated at run-time.

Comment: Can you give me example with dots so i can look it up. I'm basing this on ollydebugger instruction generating

Comment: screw it when something unhandled happens i'll fix it. for now +-* are what I will use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the [Intel Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). Specifically, section 3.7.5 "Specifying an Offset", which tells us there are two ways of doing so:

- The general form `Base + (Index * Scale) + Displacement`
- Relative to the IP: `RIP + Displacement` (64 bit mode only)

Then, examine the instruction set reference to find what are the possibilities for each instruction.

Alternatively, you can consult existing implementations of various disassemblers and emulators (e.g. [distorm](http://code.google.com/p/distorm/)) or other projects documenting this exact thing in more convenient forms (e.g. [corkami](http://code.google.com/p/corkami/))

Comment: What is the runtime cost of effective addressing vs doing the same with add, mul?

Answer (score -1):

Check out the Intel manual located at the bottom of the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOV_%28x86_instruction%29) since that should contain all of the various addressing modes supported, plus it will give you the look and function of all the other instructions.